# fade div background on load

Tags: jquery, html, fade

I'm working on fading div background on load, I found that example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nud2bfb1/58/)
The only problem if hides whole DIV and fade it, but I need to faded only DIV background.
So DIV with its text or some html inside will be shown from the beginning and its background would be fading on load.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #000000;">
<div class="feature">some text and info here</div></div>
```

Comment: Let me understand: you want the content visible and animate just the background with a fadeIn effect. Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely position the text over top of the image, the fade affects the entire thing because your text is inside the div you're fading.

Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/ubgyw1gt/3/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="bgImageContainer"></div>
  <div class="feature"><span>Some text and stuff here</span></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.feature {
   width:100%;
   background:#fff;
   z-index:100;
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
 }
 .container {
   height: 400px;
   width: 100%;
 }
 .bgImageContainer {
   display: none;
   background-color: white;
   background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/760/460/tech");
   background-size: cover;
   height:400px;
   width: 100%;
   z-index:0;
   position: absolute;
 }
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".bgImageContainer").fadeIn('slow');
})
```

Comment: in ur demo, backgorund shows and hides, but pont is that DIV with text shown from the begining and only background fades on load and stays

Comment: Yeah, fixing, missing two lines of CSS

Comment: right, but still. background should fadein on load, so content (text) is shows from the begining, but once page is load, background is fading. in ur example it's fadingut ((

Comment: Sorry misunderstood, fixed, new fiddle. Also added a container so the text centres nicely in the div. https://jsfiddle.net/ubgyw1gt/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can't fade just the background div (because, by inheritance, all children will be faded too). But you can change the setted css properties to a "default" one or create a class just for loading purposes.

An example would be:

HTML:

```
<div id="parent" class="loading">
  <div class="feature">some text and info here</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.loading {
  background-color: black;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(() => $('#parent').removeClass('loading'));
```

Comment: yeah, but stil DIV and "some text and info here" will show up only after effect and "some text and info here" insode should be visible even before effect

Comment: Then you just need to don't hide that div. Do you want to just change the background, right?

Comment: Right, but for some reason i still not undertanding what you meen :(

Comment: There's a simpler way to do this, you can just create a class `loading` for you parent div and set you custom css, and after page load you just remove that class